# Import equation from text file in Python

Tags: python, function, import

I have a complex equation which is generated into a `.txt` file. I would like to import this equation (which is all the text in the `.txt` file) and make a function from it, which can be subsequently fit.

Does anybody know how I might go about this? The equation to be fitted is at the the very bottom. My feeble attempt to import is below...

```
myfile1= open("dummyfile.txt", 'r') 
def fcn(J1,J2,T,k,g):
    return myfile1.read()
```

"dummyfile.txt" contents:

`B**2*N*(12.0*g**2*sp.exp(2.0*J2/(T*k)) + 60.0*g**2*sp.exp(6.0*J2/(T*k)) + 168.0*g**2*sp.exp(12.0*J2/(T*k)) + 360.0*g**2*sp.exp(20.0*J2/(T*k)) + 30.0*g**2*sp.exp((2.0*J1 + 4.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 168.0*g**2*sp.exp((4.0*J1 + 8.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 360.0*g**2*sp.exp((6.0*J1 + 14.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 180.0*g**2*sp.exp((8.0*J1 + 12.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 660.0*g**2*sp.exp((8.0*J1 + 22.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 660.0*g**2*sp.exp((12.0*J1 + 18.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 1092.0*g**2*sp.exp((16.0*J1 + 26.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 546.0*g**2*sp.exp((18.0*J1 + 24.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 1680.0*g**2*sp.exp((24.0*J1 + 32.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 1224.0*g**2*sp.exp((32.0*J1 + 40.0*J2)/(T*k)))/(3*T*k*(6*sp.exp(2.0*J2/(T*k)) + 10*sp.exp(6.0*J2/(T*k)) + 14*sp.exp(12.0*J2/(T*k)) + 18*sp.exp(20.0*J2/(T*k)) + 5*sp.exp((2.0*J1 + 4.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 14*sp.exp((4.0*J1 + 8.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 18*sp.exp((6.0*J1 + 14.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 9*sp.exp((8.0*J1 + 12.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 22*sp.exp((8.0*J1 + 22.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 22*sp.exp((12.0*J1 + 18.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 26*sp.exp((16.0*J1 + 26.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 13*sp.exp((18.0*J1 + 24.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 30*sp.exp((24.0*J1 + 32.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 17*sp.exp((32.0*J1 + 40.0*J2)/(T*k)) + 1))`

Comment: You should look at [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), then you should reconsider this.

Comment: For the sake of sanity, do _not_ use `eval`. But SymPy is worth exploring: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html

Comment: If you already can *read* it as plain text, you don't need to 'read' it inside a program; just copy it into the source! Providing the syntax is correct, that is.

Comment: Hello. It certainly does work to just copy and paste the text, but  the equations are generated above and vary based on what i tell the program about my system. Therefore it is much more appealing to skip this step and have the program do it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).

#### Code:

```
def build_function(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        eqn = f.read().strip()
        exec("def fcn(J1, J2, T, k, g):\n return ({})".format(eqn))
        return locals()['fcn']
```

#### Test Code:

```
fcn = build_function('file1')
print(fcn(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

#### File1:

```
J2 + T*k
```

#### Results:

```
14
```